# Hash collisions in Golang map resolving

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

If hash_key = hash(key), then bucket_num = hash_key % hmap.B and then we have a bucket containing [hash_key1],...,[hash_key8],[value1],...,[value8], how can we manage hash collisions?

I've read about open addressing and linked list. I couldn't find any prooved posts which method is used and how it implemented.

Comment: Being as lenient as possible, in trying to parse the underlying question, it still looks like you're essentially saying that you know you need to handle hash collisions, but you want someone to show you how? Please try doing this yourself first, show some code

Comment: @Elias it's a general question about the map implementation in the language. I mean I can't even provide any code as it's not provded in the documentation or packages like runtime.

Comment: So you're wasking about the specific implementation of the `map[T]T` type? The beauty of open-source software is that you can just check the code: https://go.dev/src/runtime/map.go.

Comment: The Go programming language is defined by its [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) which says something about the observable behavior of maps but nothing about their implementation, which can be any at all—as long as it supports the specified behavior. Anyway, questions about the details of particular implementations of PLs are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO as such questions have little timespan of being useful.